# Getting a numeric userId when calling request.getRemoteUser

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, portal

So here's what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to call a servlet/controller (whatever i could get to work first) from a liferay theme.

Here's what i did:
 I made a controller named XController then generated a url to call it using:

```
#set ($embeddedPortletURL = $portletURLFactory.create($request, "workspace_WAR_xportlet", $page.plid, "RESOURCE_PHASE"))
<input id="workspaceSearchUrl" value="${embeddedPortletURL}" type="hidden">
```

Then for the ajax call, i used `$("#workspaceSearchUrl").val() + "&p_p_mode=view&p_p_resource_id=doSomething"` as the url.
I was able to call the portlet no problem, however whenever i call portletRequest.getRemoteUser(), I get a userId of "2203" instead of the logged in user.

So... what exactly did i do wrong? And why is the getRemoteUser method returning me a number?

Edit:
Just to be clear, other ajax calls to other controllers return a valid user id (text).

I also tried to call a servlet instead, however calling getRemoteUser returns a null. I guess this means that servlets don't share the session with the portal?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, try to use

```
User currentUser = PortalUtil.getUser(portletRequest);
long userId = currentUser.getUserId();
```

Comment: +1 My question was "what does the number mean in request.getRemoteUser()?". It seems that it's actually the userId saved in the liferay database. What I needed was the login name. But thanks to your suggestion, i was able to retrieve the login name by getting the user class.

Comment: UserId is the Id from user_ table. From userId you can get Logged in user name using following methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user object by userId like this.

```
User user = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId);

String name = user.getFirstname();
```